# Как привести PVOID к WCHAR?

Tags: c

У меня есть буффер типа PVOID, и мне нужно разделить его на токены ориентируясь по пробелам, лежащим в буффере. Т.к. я в ядре, мне не получится использовать библиотеки, где лежат аналоги strtok, strstr для WCHAR. Я пытался находить в интернете их реализации, но не "откусывали" строку до первого пробела. Поэтому банально пойду циклом for по строчке.
Но у меня не получается это реализовать

```
for (; *(WCHAR*)buffer!=' ' && *(WCHAR*)buffer !='\0' ; ((WCHAR*)buffer)++)
    {
        //здесь я бы хотел посимвольно записать строку в новый WCHAR-массив

    }
```

Как скопировать в отдельные массивы WCHAR исходную строку PVOID, ориентируясь по пробелам?

Comment: вместо `' '` наверное надо `L' '`

Comment: Если в буфере точно `WChar` а не `UTF-8` то можно так как у вас, но добавление нужно правильно написать: `buffer = ((WCHAR*)buffer) + 1;`

Comment: Или сделайте другую переменную `WCHAR * wbuffer = buffer;`. У вас какая проблема? Написать копирование строки?

Comment: @AlexGlebe, а чем же `((WCHAR*)buffer)++` неправильно?

Comment: Инкремент работает только для `lvalue` (переменных с адресом, а не временных. Временные `rvalue` переменные могут быть в стеке, а могут находиться в регистрах процессора `ax`,`bx`,...) Ошибка компиляции будет.